# python plotly to javascript plotly

Tags: javascript, python, plotly

I would like to stay away from JavaScript and focus on analytics. Can I develop plotly graphs in Python (e.g. in Jupyter notebooks) and simply use the [write_html](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.io.write_html.html) function for developers to integrate into proper productionised websites or is this view too naive?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes. I did something similar for a work project where I wrote plotly figures to html files, and then these were iframed into a productionalized web app.

Depending on how many html files you plan to have, the size of the html files might be a constraint because by default the javascript is included in each html file and this adds `2-3 MB`. The argument `include_plotlyjs="cdn"` can help keep file sizes smaller because it references the plotly cdn instead of including the javascript directly in the html file.